# Laravel - How to Convert MySQL query to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel

I have MySQL query I want to convert to Laravel Eloquent

I have written the query in MySQL

```
SELECT a.transaction_number a.date, a.item_number, b.desc, a.variant_code, sum(a.quantity) AS quantity, a.cost
FROM `items_details` AS a
JOIN `items` AS b ON b.id = a.item_number
WHERE a.item_number = 0101010
GROUP BY a.variant_code
ORDER BY transaction_number, variant_code
```

Comment: Is there a particular bit of the conversion that's confusing to you? The Laravel docs are pretty good.

Comment: Are you wanting to use Eloquent for its relationships or literally just Laravel's query builder?

Comment: just laravel query builder

Comment: Query builder docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems pretty simple.

```
DB::table('items_details as a')
    ->join('items b', 'b.id', '=', 'a.item_number')
    ->select([
        'a.transaction_number',
        'a.date',
        'a.item_number',
        'b.desc',
        'a.variant_code',
        DB::raw('sum(a.quantity) AS quantity'),
        'a.cost'
    ])
    ->where('a.item_number', '=', 10101010)
    ->groupBy('a.variant_code')
    ->orderBy('transaction_number')
    ->orderBy('variant_code');
```

**Note: Not Tested**